# Does anyone know a method to drag and select letters from a grid in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm developing a word search in react native.

The whole part of the grid and randomization of letters is ready, but I'm finding is difficult in selection the word search.

Does anyone know a way to make the selection?

follow the code:

this is the logic to create the grid and add the letters

```
class WordSearchGame extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        gridLetras: this.gerarGridAleatorio(),
        listaPalavras: [
          "PESCADOR",
          "BOMBEIRO",
          "PADEIRO",
          "MECANICO",
          "POLICIAL",
        ],
        palavrasEncontradas: [],
        
      };
    }
  
    gerarGridAleatorio = () => {
      const gridSizeX = 17; // Tamanho do grid horizontal
      const gridSizeY = 12; // Tamanho do grid vertical
      const grid = [];
  
      for (let i = 0; i < gridSizeX; i++) {
        const row = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < gridSizeY; j++) {
          row.push("");
        }
        grid.push(row);
      }
  
      return grid;
    };
  
    preencherGridComLetrasAleatorias = () => {
      const { gridLetras } = this.state;
      const alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; // Letras possíveis
  
      for (let i = 0; i < gridLetras.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < gridLetras[i].length; j++) {
          if (gridLetras[i][j] === "") {
            // Preencher com letra aleatória
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);
            gridLetras[i][j] = alphabet[randomIndex];
          }
        }
      }
  
      this.setState({ gridLetras });
    };
```

And this one to add the words to the grid

```
adicionarPalavraAoGrid = (palavra) => {
      const { gridLetras } = this.state;
      const gridSize = gridLetras.length;
  
      const directions = ["horizontal", "vertical"];
      const selectedDirection =
        directions[Math.floor(Math.random() * directions.length)];
  
      if (selectedDirection === "horizontal") {
        let x, y;
        do {
          x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gridSize - palavra.length + 1));
          y = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
        } while (!this.ehPosicaoValida(gridLetras, palavra, x, y, "horizontal"));
  
        for (let i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
          gridLetras[y][x + i] = palavra[i];
        }
      } else {
        let x, y;
        do {
          x = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
          y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gridSize - palavra.length + 1));
        } while (!this.ehPosicaoValida(gridLetras, palavra, x, y, "vertical"));
  
        for (let i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
          gridLetras[y + i][x] = palavra[i];
        }
      }
  
      this.setState({ gridLetras });
    };
  
    ehPosicaoValida = (grid, palavra, x, y, direcao) => {
      const gridSize = grid.length;
  
      if (direcao === "horizontal") {
        for (let i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
          if (grid[y][x + i] !== "" && grid[y][x + i] !== palavra[i]) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
          if (grid[y + i][x] !== "" && grid[y + i][x] !== palavra[i]) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
  
      return true;
    };
  
    componentDidMount() {
      this.state.listaPalavras.forEach((palavra) => {
        this.adicionarPalavraAoGrid(palavra);
      });
  
      this.preencherGridComLetrasAleatorias();
    }
```